# "Ubuntu software" doesn't work

Tags: software-center, hp

Good evening everyone,
I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on this afternoon. I found an issue I cannot cope with:

At the fist time "Ubuntu software" opened, and showed that there were 18 updates to be made. After I set them up, I turned off computer.

- At the following computer turning on, I noticed that "Ubuntu software" didn't open anymore, so now, I cannot see the apps anymore.

How can I reset the "Ubuntu Software"?
Thanks,

Best regards!

P.S.
I almost forgot. the description of PC:
I've installed Ubuntu 16.04lts on a 2007 PC. It's a:
 "HP media center PC m7000". 
I had windows Vista on it. Now, I've made a dual boot splitting the partitions. So the pc has 2 operating systems. I installed Ubuntu so set it back to life, since it's quite a lot time I didn't use it.

Comment: Press the Super key (the one that used to be the Windows key) or click the top button in the launcher bar on the left. Then, type "software". An icon of a shopping bag will appear. Click on it. That is "Ubuntu Software". Does that work?

Comment: I Did what You suggested but it doesn't open

Comment: OK. Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and type `killall gnome-software` (Enter)  followed by `gnome-software --gapplication-service`. The software center should appear in a couple of seconds.

Comment: Doesn't work too

Comment: The last command will have given you an error message. Please edit your question and paste the message into it.

Comment: famiglia@PC-Famiglia:~$ killall gnome-software
famiglia@PC-Famiglia:~$ gnome-software --gapplication-service

Comment: But then nothing happened

Comment: No error message means the program has started correctly. Doesn't it show up with Alt + Tab either?